# Xamarin Studio: Storyboard Localization/Language File

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to user different languages in my ios app, programmed with Xamarin Studio in C#. I know the way to use language translation files, but I don't know, how I can use the automatic translation with the id of my control. Found some examples where the ID of the objects was for example MWt-Ya-pMf. Then you could use this id to automatic translate with the translation file: "MWt-Ya-pMf.normalTitle" = "Save";

But now, I only found ids like 345, 235,... I tried it for my button with "345.normalTitle"="test"; in my language file or "345.title"="test"; but without success.

Can anybody tell me how it works now?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself, but thx anymore, here's my solution:

I had to copy the storyboard file in a folder named Base.lproj (root) and I also created a file e.g. in Resources/de.lproj/MyStoryboard.strings (Bundle Resource).
Then I could use "345.normalTitle" = "Titlestring"; to change the title of my button.

Comment: I have the same structure as you, but translation do not work